# C++ namespace with common used instances of the class like Unity's Vector3.Up

Tags: c++, class, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I have a namespace, Vector2, (inside another namespace, CHIM) which represents a 2D Vector. We use the zero vector ( [0, 0] ) multiple times, therefore, we would like to be able to write something like:

```
Vector2 a = CHIM::Vector2::ZERO;
```

Which is something commonly used in Unity's game engine.
The problem is, class Vector2 cannot [obviously] contain a member of its type, since it would have infinite size.

We currently solved this by making a static function that returns a Vector2 representing a zero vector. But this makes it such that the code has to run a function:

```
Vector2 a = CHIM::Vector2::ZERO();
```

As you can see, it's a bit more verbose, although the result is the same.

Is there any way to make this?

[EDIT]

Here's a simple example of what the code looks like:

```
#define CHIM_API 

namespace CHIM {

union CHIM_API Vector2 {


    struct { float x, y; };
    struct { float u, v; };
    struct { float w, h; };
    struct { float width, height; };
    float vec[2];

    Vector2() : x(0), y(0) {};
    Vector2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    inline const static Vector2 ZERO = {0, 0};  // ERROR:  Variable has incomplete type 'const Vector2'
   
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't `inline` incomplete data types

```
namespace CHIM {

union Vector2 {
    struct { float x, y; };
    struct { float u, v; };
    struct { float w, h; };
    struct { float width, height; };
    float vec[2];

    Vector2() : x(0), y(0) {};
    Vector2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    const static Vector2 ZERO;
};
}
```

Define `const CHIM::Vector2 CHIM::Vector2::ZERO;` in .cpp.

See [Static Members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

> However, if the declaration uses constexpr or inline (since C++17) specifier, the member must be declared to have complete type.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Just two things:
1) When you say define in the .cpp, you just mean
```
const static Vector2 ZERO = {0, 0};
```
right?

2) Why can't we use inline in this case?

Comment: Because it's a language rule. See the reference.

Comment: True, the out-of-line definition is required here. If it was a template, then `inline`/`constexpr` would be fine to define the member inline.